# Use sed to replace random number.number with a variable

Tags: bash, sed

I want to use sed to change a line that looks like this in a text file:
encoding="ISO-8859-1" target="1.1" 
Where the value of target is unknown but a number[dot]number to a number in an var called NEWNUMBER in a bash script.
I need to identify with that full line (encoding="ISO-8859-1" target=)
As an example NEWNUMBER=2.9
I just can't seem to get it right but i'm pretty new to sed.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you might miss to use:

1. `-r` parameter to run with extended regular expressions,
2. `-i` parameter to make a replacement right in file - you may want to use it when you'll be sure that your expression works correctly - otherwise you may potentially corrupt the file,
3. `[^\"]` to conveniently match everything except specific character. Notice I have escaped double quote since your example is going to use some variable from bash script and sed contents should be surrounded with double quote to inject the variable properly.

Rest is what you might do the right way as long as you have the right idea about:

- Usage of `+` (at least one occurrence) or `*` (zero or more occurences) following some single character or class (for example: `\w` to match letter, number or underscore), alternatively following multiple character/class matches (for example: `[\w-]` to match letter, number, underscore or hyphen)

  - so with `[\w-]+` you'll match strings like `ISO-8859-1`.
- Add up usage of groups, surrounding anything proper match with `( )` and using that match on the right side of sed replace-all (`sed 's/pattern/replacement/g'`) by referring to subsequent group matches as `\1`, `/2` and so on...

  - For example answering Agent 007's famous greeting casually: `echo "I'm Bond, James Bond." | sed -r "s/I'm (\w+), (\w+) \w+./Hello, \2 \1/g"`).
- You may want to start your match with `^` that would mark a beginning of line and end with `$` that would mark end of line (practically ensuring that your match will match only whole line, not part of it).

Please share your attempt, so I'll be able to get to the point. If you'll make it right, please share your experience too, so others will be potentially able to avoid same trouble.

---

As a response to comment, I have added alternative solution using perl and lookbehind:
`perl -pi.bak -e 's/(?<=encoding="ISO-8859-1" target=")(\d+\.\d+)/'$NEWNUMBER'/g' test`

- `-i.bak` means that you will make change directly on input file and save a backup copy with `.bak` extension
- `-p` adds a printing loop allowing to process each line of input file - command would not succeed without this even on one-liner
- `-e` allows you to run this as one-liner script instead of providing script file
- `(?<=pattern)` is a lookbehind - it makes `pattern` a thing that has to be right before your match, but it won't be a part of match (making it an alternative to usage of groups in regex)

  - You can use it in `grep` too (with `-P` parameter for perl regex), but apparently not in `sed`

Comment: I tried a lot but got this working   `sed -r -i 's/(encoding="ISO-8859-1" target=")([0-9].[0-9]")/\1'$NEWNUMBER'"/g' myfile.txt` I guess it can be made better than my hack attempt at sed

Comment: It's fine. Only thing I can comment on is potential use of characters marking line beginning and line end - you may consider adding them. I have found a way to do this using lookbehind (see my answer), but you have to switch from `sed` to `perl` to run it... and it doesn't actually make the solution more readable. Depends on one's taste.